# What do you call this open food vessel?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

[image: an industrial steel container used for mixing chocolate]

I am thinking of an open food vessel, conical shaped, made to create chocolate, but I don't know if there's a proper name for it.

Comment: Why the downvote on a week-old question? Can someone please explain why this question deserves 4 downvotes because I (the editor) don't know.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Q: "Why the downvote on a week-old question?" A: "Because it's bad." / Q: "Can someone please explain why this question deserves 4 downvotes because I (the editor) don't know." A: "Because four people think that it's bad."

Comment: @Eden0516  Very thorough analysis.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, I can't agree with you more.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Why can't you figure it out?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Maybe there are more than four users who think that this question is bad, but they just didn't downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would call those vats. Some might call them mixing bowls, but that term conjures up something smaller, in my mind.

Comment: An image search for chocolate vat confirms this.